# DFS BFS with cost in PROLOG

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

find the total cost of traveling from the start node
to the end node using breadth-first search and depth-first search using prolog. Given
here the start node as node “0” and the end node be “4”. The edge connecting any two
nodes depicts the cost between those two nodes:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you encountering? See ["How Do I Ask a Good Question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is path finding problem.

1. looking up all path.
2. added paths to cost.
3. select a minimal cost or max cost path.

https://gist.github.com/MPhilis/0724504eb7a8e0bd30fdaff509718a0f

[https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15.html](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Ejrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15.html)